# How to display the vertices while in object mode?

Tags: bezier-curves

how to show vertex in object mode ? I'm in object mode and executing 'curve simplify' , but as i change the parameter , it's hard to see how far i've done the simplification without seeing the vertices. So i have to go back and forth between object and edit mode to check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Parent a colored little icosphere under the object and turn on Duplication - Verts:

[image]

This lets you see even vertices on straight edges of ngons, something wire edges don't show.

Answer (score 2):

Enable Wire under Display in the Object tab of the Properties Panel. Draw All Edges will draw edges even if the surface is flat.

[image]

Comment: as i wrote, i 'm doing 'simplify curve" (addon) . So i turn this wire ON , but i won't visible in curve object.